# Java : constructor error "method 'void <init>()' not found"

Tags: java, constructor

In main method, I create a new object with a non-argument constructor. But I have runtime error on this line.

Could you please explain why?

```
class Student {
    String name;
    int age;

    Student() {
        Student();
    }

    void Student() {
        Student("James", 25);
    }

    void Student(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}

public class Test_03_09 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student s = new Student(); // Runtime error
        System.out.println(s.name + ":" + s.age); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove `Student() { ... }`, and then remove `void` from `void Student() { ... }`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error, can you please include the entire callstack into the question?

Comment: Add error stack in description. Thx

Comment: The real answer: because syntax matters. Every character you put into your code matters. A constructor is NOT a method. Pick up a good book and LEARN these things. There is no point in trying to learn language syntax by *experimenting*.

Comment: There was no mistake. it was a bad example because, the was to mix this java file with other an other java file containing already an other Student java file, and the JVM was loading the wrong .class file.

Answer (score 3):

As there are so many bad answers:

It boils down to simply use correct syntax for the Student class constructors:

```
class Student {
    String name;
    int age;

    Student() {
      this("James", 25);
    }

    Student(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Note: the "runtime error" is most likely an artefact of the whole code NOT compiling, and your IDE doing the wrong thing.

Answer (score -1):

There was no mistake. it was a bad example because, the was to mix this java file with other an other java file containing already an other Student java file, and the JVM was loading the wrong .class file.